# Converting signed hex integer to display negative decimal integer on terminal in C code

Tags: digital-logic, pic, c, hex

I am trying to take a signed hex number and display it on the terminal as a negative decimal number so that it can be easily read. I am having a hard time working through the logic on how to make this happen. I am using a PIC16F15345 and Real Term as my terminal. My UART is up and running correctly.

Problem Example:

Hex: B6

Display dec value: -74

I have thought about first converting the hex number to binary by creating a large if statement for each byte and then concatenate them together, but I am not quite sure on where to go next for converting to decimal. I need this code to be efficient and easily readable as it is going into some documentation I have and all of my ideas seem very complex and long. I feel like I am overthinking this.

Thank you for the help

Comment: When you refer to the number you want to 'convert' and display as a "hex integer", do you mean that you have 2 ASCII characters, for example a `B` and a `6`, or do you really just have a number in an 8-bit variable in your code?

Comment: I am trying to display the decimal value, and what I have is a received 8-bit value from my radio module that I am storing in a variable in my code. I then want to convert that 8-bit number to its correct negative decimal number for easy readability on the terminal.

Comment: Ok - here's the thing - it's not a "hex number". It's just a number in a variable. If the variable type you've put the number into is signed, then the number is signed. What you're really wanting to do is convert or print it as decimal. Typically, `printf` will suffice - or to be safe and correct, probably `snprintf` would be better. If you really want to be a sadist (or you think you can/need to optimize things) then you could do the conversion 'manually' with an `if` for the sign bit and a couple of `/` division and `%` modulus operations for the digits.

Comment: ... and once you've found the 100's, 10's and 1's using `/` and `%`, don't forget to add the ASCII `0` character to make them printable.

Answer (score 0):

no conversion is needed, just cast it to signed, then proceed normally.

Answer (score 0):

There are signed and unsigned variables. 1st) you need to declare signed variable of 8-bit size. If it doesn't exist then you may declare as signed variable of 16bit (or whatever bit value the PIC is made). The MSB bit is a sign bit, so how to make you 8 bit number to get the sign? You do shift left for 8 places and then do arithmetic shift right to 8 places back. With arithmetic shift the sign is preserved. Then use Printf function with the right format.